# FCM on Android does not trigger `onNewIntent` when app was previously launched from notification

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to open a proper screen when my app is launched from notification. I found a scenario when it doesn't work as I thought it should.

So here is first scenario when it works as it should work:

1. App is launched from launcher icon
2. App is put into background
3. FCM notification shows up
4. Upon clicking it `onNewIntent` of default activity is called.

But when app is first launched from FCM notification then step 4. never happens:

1. FCM notification shows up
2. App is launched from FCM notification
3. App is put into background
4. Another FCM notification shows up
5. Upon clicking it `onNewIntent` of default activity **IS NOT CALLED**

I found it really problematic to work with and to code against. Is this a bug or I am just missing something?

**EDIT**: Default activity `launchMode` is set to `singleTask` in manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the previous answer, onNewIntent is called for activities that set launchMode to "singleTop".

So first thing you should set up is the manifest file. Set the activity's launchMode to *singleTop*. Another thing is to add an intent filter with an action tag.

sample:

```
<activity android:name="youPackage.YourActivity"
          android:launchMode="singleTop">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="youPackage.ACTION">
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And, in your service, you can call new intent provided the action you define in the intent-filter.

sample:

```
Intent i = new Intent("youPackage.ACTION");
```

Reference:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)
- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/action-element.html

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure to override onNewIntent in the **launcher activity**. In my case, it was the splash screen.

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            for (String key : intent.getExtras().keySet()) {
                Object value = intent.getExtras().get(key);
                Log.d("data ", "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
            }
        }
    }
```